# Different types of URL

Tags: php, url

I see websites where they have an index page and then their url reads

> index.php?page=page

I was wondering how i would do that for my own website using a folder called pages and loading the content of those pages onto my index page while using that url type.

If that makes sense.

Comment: try to use pretty urls through htaccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you have following structure:

```
index.php
pages
    page1.php
    page2.php
    pageN.php
```

So make use of `$_GET` to get the page name:

**index.php**

```
if(isset($_GET['page']) && !empty($_GET['page'])) {
    $pagename = $_GET['page'];
    if(file_exists("pages/$pagename.php")){
        include_once "pages/$pagename.php";
    }
}
```

When URL has `index.php?page=page1`, it checks for `page1.php` inside pages folder. If file exists, it includes that file inside `index.php`. Similarly for other pages.

---

This is a simple outline idea though. You can develop further, introduce validations. And again, use pretty URLs to make it better for SEO. It can be done by adding few lines to `.htaccess` file. URL then will be `domain.com/page1` or something as you configure.

Comment: Thank you so much. I wasn't entirely sure as to whether I had it right but this is exactly how I wanted it done. I had it completely wrong

Comment: What would i do to have a default page so that if its only index.php and no page= blah blah.

Comment: Add an else part. Either include or add a static content there